# Customised different color zone with range Seekbar

Tags: android, android-widget, android-custom-view

How to customize seek bar like below attached image?

Also wanted to the know the color on which the seekbar falls?

[image]

Comment: Why same question repeats are you guys brothers ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42289903/how-to-customize-seekbar-like-below-attached-image-i-also-want-to-know-which-zo

Comment: he is my friend and i'm searching the solution for him... if you know anything about that.. share with us.

Answer (score 1):

You can use library for customize `seekbar`

Here is example, Try this -

[Seekbar Library](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3118)

**Gradle Dependency**

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.rtugeek:ColorSeekBar:1.2.2'
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But, it has only one circle to choose. actually I want two circle to select range like start and end....

Comment: There is another library I found for two thumbs, hope it will Help you. 
[Two Thumb Seekbar](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3976). If it doesn't help you then you have to use two `seekbar` and manage it according to your requirement.

Comment: ya.. As in the multiple thumbs part in the Two thumb seekbar example. i have to work it with two thumbs and detect which color range i'm in.. that what i want..